# NInject factory binding by convention

Tags: c#, ninject

I've an assembly: `Asbly1` which declares this interface:

```
public interface IFieldFactory<T>
{
    T createFieldObject(string fieldKey, object fieldValue);
}
```

I'm trying to expose this interface in order to create objects providing a `fieldKey` and a `fieldValue`.

Form an another assembly `AnotherAsbly` I create a `IFieldFactory<Domain.MetaInfoValue>` concrete factory:

```
public class FieldFactory : IFieldFactory<Domain.MetaInfoValue>
{

    public Domain.MetaInfoValue createFieldObject(string fieldKey, object fieldValue)
    {
        Type fieldValueType = fieldValue.GetType();
        if (fieldValueType.Equals(typeof(String)))
        {
            return new Domain.StringMetaInfoValue(fieldKey, (string)fieldValue);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

From assembly `Asbly1` I want to get every `IFactory<T>` implementation and use them according to `T` generic type.

I guess I need to bind `IFactory<T>` to their whichever implementations:

```
public class FieldFactoryModule : Ninject.Modules.NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        this.Bind(scanner => scanner.FromAssembliesMatching("*")
            .SelectAllClasses()
            .InheritedFrom(typeof(IFieldFactory<>))
            .BindToFactory()
            .Configure(c => c.InSingletonScope())
        );
    }
}
```

So, after that, there is the possibility that exists several implementations of `IFieldFactory<T>`. The question is, how can I obtain the concreate factory according to `T = runtime provided type`?

I guess it can do as:

```
UIFramework.Proxy.Extension.IoC.NInjectKernelHolder.Instance.Kernel.Get(
    runtimeType,
    new Ninject.Parameters.Parameter("fieldKey", propertyName, true),
    new Ninject.Parameters.Parameter("fieldValue", assignedValue, true)
);
```